# Can't upload files unless I comment out htaccess entries

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site that is built on concrete5 (not by me). Now, I added a few lines to the htaccess to add the trailing slash after my urls as the site was loading over both versions.

However, now I cannot upload files to the site. I am just getting errors. There is also an option for users to upload a photo and they get an error too.

The only work around I have is that I can go into htaccess and comment out the lines I added, save it and then upload and the remove the `#`'s. Whilst this lets me upload in the short term, it's not a viable solution as regular users cannot do this.

**My `.htaccess` is the following:**

```
# -- concrete5 urls start --
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
# -- concrete5 urls end --
```

I comment out these lines for it to let me upload:

```
# -- concrete5 urls start --
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
# -- concrete5 urls end --
```

Whilst it looks like that i can upload but lose the trailing slashes so the urls are all messed up.

Anyone know what is going on? FYI I am not a developer but can understand to a degree.

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated all your internal links (and form submission URLs) to include the trailing slash?

My guess is that you are submitting the form to a URL that does not include the trailing slash. The 301 redirect that follows will lose any submitted POST data (as the request is *converted* to GET).

You need to make sure that you are submitting your form to the canonical URL.